# How to solve a set of nonlinear equations multiple times when one of the coefficient of the variable changes

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, scipy-optimize, fsolve

I want to solve for the variables s,L for different values of t. t is a part of my second equation and its values changes, I tried to solve for s,L for different t values then append the values to an empty list so that i could have different values of s, L for diiferent t values. But what i was getting is just an empty list.PLease help me with this
[image]

```
from  scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
import math as m
q0=0.0011
thetas,thetai,thetar=0.43,0.1,0.05
ks=0.0022#m/hr
psib=-0.15# m
lamda=1
eta=2+3*lamda
ki=8.676*10**(-8)
si=0.13157
t=np.array([3,18,24])

S=0.02/24
delta=-0.1001
b=[]
n=[]
for i in range(3):
    def equations(p):
        s, L = p
        f1=(ks*s**(3+(2/lamda))-(psib/(1-eta))*(((ki*si**(-1/lamda))-(ks*s**(3+(1/lamda))))/L)-q0)
        f2=(L*(s*(thetas-thetar))+S*t[i]*0.5*(m.exp(-delta*psib*(-1+s**(-1/lamda))))-(q0-ki)*t[i])
        return(f1,f2)

        s,L=fsolve(equations,([0.19,0.001]))
        b.append(s)
        n.append(L)
print(b)
print(n)
```

Comment: For a problem like this: relax, take a step back from the code. A blackboard and chalk, or a notebook and pen, will be much more helpful than a screen and keyboard.

Comment: In other words: could you please add the actual equations to your post? They are likely more relevant to the question than your code.

Comment: I added the actual equations, solving by using pen and paper is a tedious task

Comment: That empty list solution might be correct.  Perhaps there is no solution in the range you've given.  These are non-linear in (s, L).  Do you understand what fsolve function is doing to solve them?

Comment: There is a solution, i can solve for one value of t at a time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to evaluate this system with an adjustable parameter. You could plug each value in before solving, which would make it compatible with additional solvers if `fsolve` didn't give you the desired results, or you could utilize the `args` parameter within `fsolve`. If I set up a dummy system such that I try to find `x,y,z` for some initial guess, and step through a parameter, I can append a preallocated solution array with the results

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

a = np.linspace(0,10,21)

def equations(variables, a):
    x,y,z = variables
    eq1 = x+y+z*a
    eq2 = x-y-z
    eq3 = x*y*x*a   
    return tuple([eq1, eq2, eq3])

solutions = np.zeros((21,3))
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    solutions[idx] = fsolve(equations, [-1,0,1], args=(i))

print(solutions)
```

which gives

```
[[ 5.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 9.86864911e-17 -2.96059473e-16  3.94745964e-16]
 [ 1.62191889e-39 -1.28197512e-16  1.28197512e-16]
 [-2.15414908e-17 -1.07707454e-16  8.61659633e-17]
 [ 2.19853562e-28  6.59560686e-28 -4.39707124e-28]
 [-1.20530409e-28 -2.81237621e-28  1.60707212e-28]
 [-3.34744837e-17 -6.69489674e-17  3.34744837e-17]
 [ 6.53567253e-17  1.17642106e-16 -5.22853803e-17]
 [-3.14018492e-17 -5.23364153e-17  2.09345661e-17]
 [-5.99115518e-17 -9.41467242e-17  3.42351724e-17]
 [ 5.18199815e-29  7.77299722e-29 -2.59099907e-29]
 [-2.70691440e-17 -3.90998747e-17  1.20307307e-17]
 [-2.57288510e-17 -3.60203914e-17  1.02915404e-17]
 [-2.44785120e-17 -3.33797891e-17  8.90127708e-18]
 [-1.27252940e-28 -1.69670587e-28  4.24176466e-29]
 [ 2.24744956e-56  2.93897250e-56 -6.91522941e-57]
 [-2.12580678e-17 -2.73318015e-17  6.07373366e-18]
 [-2.03436865e-17 -2.57686696e-17  5.42498307e-18]
 [-3.89960988e-17 -4.87451235e-17  9.74902470e-18]
 [-1.87148635e-17 -2.31183608e-17  4.40349730e-18]
 [-7.19531738e-17 -8.79427680e-17  1.59895942e-17]]
```